# Bootstrap Failure when trying to install Spark on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am using this link to install Spark Cluster on EMR(Elastic Map Reduce on Amazon) https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/4926593393724923

For creating a Spark cluster I run the following command and my cluster is running into bootstrap failure every single time. I am not able to resolve this issue, and it will be great if any could help me here.

```
aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.2 \
--instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --ec2-attributes \
KeyName=MYKEY --applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions \
Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark
```

SOLVED : Use this:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.7 \
--instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --service-role \
EMR_DefaultRole --ec2-attributes \
KeyName=emr,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
--applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions \
Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark
```

Comment: Error Image <https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652592303/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of the answer (it took a bit of back and forth in comments) that worked for this user given the user's SSH key and IAM roles:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.7 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --ec2-attributes KeyName=emr,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark
```

Explanations of EMR IAM roles can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles-creatingroles.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-iam-roles-launch-jobflow.html

Answer (score 2):

The *4th* point under the section `Spark with YARN on an Amazon EMR cluster` at the link you provide says the following:

> Substitute "MYKEY" value for the KeyName parameter with the name of the EC2 key pair you want to use to SSH into the master node of your EMR cluster.

As far as I can see, you have not changed the value of `MYKEY` for your own EC2 key name. You should try changing its value to an existing EC2 key name you have already created.

In case you still do not have a keypair, you can created following several methods, one of which is described in this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html).

**Update** (from the comments below)

From your pictures, it seems there is a problem downloading the bootstrap action file from S3. I am not sure what the cause of the problem could be, but you might want to change the AMI and launch EMR with a different AMI version, `3.0`, for example.

Comment: I have replaced the MYKEY with my EC2 instance key pair name. The command I just took from the tutorial link. Check my error file https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652592303/

Comment: I am able to create Spark Cluster but that is going into boostrap error. I am adding more images here

Comment: ERROR BOOTSTRAP FAILURE https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652593606/ and I have edited the command as well. Thanks

Comment: I tried version 3.0, 3.1 and 3.7 but all are going into bootstrap error. Could you tell me is there any other tutorial or way to run spark on EMR? https://www.pinterest.com/rakeshrsukla/ideas-for-big-data/

Comment: In that case, I am prone to think that the cause of the error resides on *Amazon* and not on your script. I might be incorrect, and anyone else could have other insight of the error, though.

Comment: Does your instance profile "emr" have sufficient policy permissions to access s3://support.elasticmapreduce/* ?

Comment: Good point. I would say that Amazon's bucket (which contains the Spark package) is rather public for everyone, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Not the Amazon bucket but the policy on the role you are using. I see you are using the default service role, try using the default EMR instance/profile as well which is "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole" instead of "emr".

Comment: I created a new instance Webserver and gave him EMR_EC2_DefaultRole policy but still I am running into validation error. See the error https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652639269/

Comment: I checked my account and my EMR EC2 DefaultRole is present https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652639311/

Comment: Like this:  aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.7 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --ec2-attributes KeyName=emr,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --applications Name=Hive --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark

Comment: @ChristopherB, you might want to write a new answer with your solution, it might be easier to find it afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to directly start spark cluster in EMR.

Step 1 - Go to the EMR section in aws and click on create cluster.

Step 2 - Go to bootstrap actions in the configuration and add this line 
s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/429953095652701745/

Step 3 - Click on create cluster

Your cluster will start in minutes :)